# Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference During adding one spring boot applciation to another?

Tags: java, javabeans, beancreationexception, jmix

Scenario :
I have a springboot applcation which perform a batch like functionality (Reading data from s3 processing and writing to sql tables).

I also have a seperate Jmix application.
So in need to add the batch to this jmix application so that i can run the batch from jmix application

I was able to add it in buid.gradle and i done like below in main class of jmix application

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.publicismedia.uniquebatchjava"})
@EnableJmixDataRepositories(basePackages = {})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.publicismedia.uniquebatchjava.repository"})
```

So that we can use the beans in the Jmix app(`scanBasePackages = {"com.publicismedia.uniquebatchjava"}`)
Jmix tries to create bean for all repository class whether it is on main application or dependency application
So i am adding this `@EnableJmixDataRepositories(basePackages = {})` to avoid jmix to scan nothing and `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.publicismedia.uniquebatchjava.repository"})` to allow jpa to scan dependent application

And the error now is

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'tokenStore'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'sec_TokenStore' defined in class path
> resource
> [io/jmix/autoconfigure/securityoauth2/SecurityOAuth2AutoConfiguration$JdbcTokenStoreConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tokenStore' parameter
> 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'stellantisroiApplication': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'batchExecuter'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'batchExecuter': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'batchConfigRepository'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'batchConfigRepository' defined in
> com.publicismedia.uniquebatchjava.repository.BatchConfigRepository
> defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> StellantisroiApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner
> bean)#51e0629a' of type
> [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
> bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name '(inner bean)#51e0629a': Cannot resolve
> reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
> argument; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'jmix_Liquibase' defined in class path
> resource
> [io/jmix/autoconfigure/data/JmixLiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'liquibase' parameter
> 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is
> currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Do any one has any solution or simply how to add a spring boot maven app in to other spring boot maven app considering `com.package1.*` is main app and `com.package2.*` as dependent application

Comment: I only see *Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?* Not the error you mentioned in the title

Comment: for the above error stack do you know any solution

Comment: Not without related code

Answer (score 0):

First of all please fix the title as it says something different that enclosed stacktrace. Please read

> Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

It means that you have a bean "A" which depends on another bean "B" but "B" depends on "A" and this is the reason of a circular reference. Of course this cycle can be longer, for example: `A -> B -> C -> A`. You have to follow good design principles and remove this cycle somehow or you can use `@Lazy` annotation on a field to initiate a bean later (by default it's eager dependency).